# ath10k_pci not working with Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 wireless adapter remains UNCLAIMED

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo, atheros, dmesg

After installing Ubuntu 19.10 in my Lenovo e41-25, it showed wireless adapter not found. when I followed the troubleshooting instructions I got the following results:

```
######### lshw -c network ##############
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 31
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: cap_list
   configuration: latency=0

########### dmesg |grep ath10k_pci##############
[   13.376994] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to iomap BAR0
[   13.377051] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to claim device: -5
[   13.377143] ath10k_pci: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
```

how can I fix this problem to get the wireless adapter working?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI?

Comment: Yes I installed ubuntu in uefi

Comment: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-C-E-K-M-N-and-V-Series-Notebooks/Lenovo-E41-25-Wifi-not-working-only-in-any-Linux/m-p/5024691 did you try this?

Comment: @Jeremy31 the method you posted in the above forum worked for me. Thank you.